# Tratamiento con operadores logicos para Ubicaciones (Latitud y Longitud) en Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Requiero de su apoyo para despejar dudas con la aplicación de operadores lógicos en columnas de dataframe:

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
 Cliente     Fecha      Latitud    Longitud
Cliente1  2016-01-20   19.345500  -98.837600
Cliente2  2016-01-20   18.567500  -99.777600
Cliente3  2016-01-20   20.832500  -100.567600
Cliente4  2016-01-20   20.123500  -100.237600
Cliente5  2016-01-20   21.763500  -99.797600
```

Deseo agregar una columna adicional al dataframe mediante una función que diga el sector o tramo, por ejemplo; el **tramo metropolitano** tiene ubicaciones (Inicio:  19.246500, -99.658600, Fin: 20.942500, -100.777600) y si la ubicación 19.345500, -98.837600 del Cliente1 se encuentra en ese rango del tramo metropolitano, me diga en la nueva columna que se encuentra en el sector o tramo metropolitano, por otro lado; el **tramo foráneo** tiene ubicaciones (Inicio:  19.1440392, -98.948600, Fin: 20.826500,-101.877600), si la ubicación 20.832500, -100.567600 del cliente 3 se encuentra en dicho tramo foráneo, en la columna tramo o sector, me diga que se encuentra en tramo foráneo. Y sino se encuentra en ninguno, diga otro tramo.

He realizado lo siguiente:

```
if any(df[(df['Latitud'] >= 19.246500) & (df['Latitud'] <= 20.942500) & (df['Longitud'] <= -99.658600) & (df['Longitud'] >= -100.777600)]):
    
    df['Tramo'] = 'Zona Metropolitana'

elif any(df[(df['Latitud'] >= 19.1440392) & (df['Latitud'] <= 20.826500) & (df['Longitud'] <= -98.948600) & (df['Longitud'] >= -101.877600)]):
    
    df['Tramo'] = 'Foraneo'

else:

    df['Tramo'] = 'Otro'
```

A pesar de estar los rangos de las ubicaciones están correctamente delimitados, los resultados para todas las ubicaciones del dataframe es **Zona Metropolitana** .

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: los valores de inicio corresponde al inicio de la latitud y de la longitud??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma fácil, sencilla (y con menos código) de hacerlo es usando el método `apply()` de los *DataFrame*, este método permite *aplicarle* una operación a una columna, fila ó a todo el DataFrame. Por defecto se itera en las columnas, pero se puede cambiar haciendo que itere por las filas, este método acepta una función como parámetro, y nosotros le pasaremos una `lambda` peroo... para hacer el código mas legible también crearemos otra función que se encargue de *catalogar* los datos según  su rango.

```py
#creamos una funcion que nos devuelve el tramo según sus valores
def tramo(lat,longi):
    if 19.246500 <= lat <= 20.942500 and -100.777600 <=longi<= -99.658600: 
         return "metropolitana"
    elif 19.1440392<=lat<=20.826500 and -101.877600<=longi<=-98.948600:
        return "foraneo"
    else: return "otro"
```

Ahora simplemente tenemos que llamar esta función al iterar en el DF

```
df["Tramo"] = df.apply(lambda x: tramo(float(x["Latitud"]),float(x["Longitud"])),axis=1)
```

Convertimos a `float()` cada dato de cada fila (Latitud y Longitud) y se lo pasamos a nuestra función `tramo` que retorna `metropolitano`,`foraneo` u `otro` según los valores y ese resultado será asignado a la columna `Tramo` que estamos creando. Con `axis=1` indicamos que itere en las filas y no en las columnas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. También funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes es evaluar un solo dato del `dataframe`

Cuando haces esto:
`any(df[(...condicionales...)])` estas evaluando si hay algún valor verdadero, pero como es un dataframe  con valores eso cuenta como verdadero.

La solución seria evaluar directamente el valor

```
if (19.246500 <= df['Latitud'] <= 20.942500) and (-100.777600 <= df['Longitud'] <= -99.658600):
    df['Tramo'] = 'Zona Metropolitana'
elif (19.1440392 <= df['Latitud'] <= 20.826500) and (-101.877600 <= df['Longitud'] <= -98.948600):
    df['Tramo'] = 'Foraneo'
else:
    df['Tramo'] = 'Otro'
```

Además tendría que hacerlo por cada fila (cliente):

```
for row in df.rows():
    if (19.246500 <= row['Latitud'] <= 20.942500) and (-100.777600 <= row['Longitud'] <= -99.658600):
        row['Tramo'] = 'Zona Metropolitana'
    elif (19.1440392 <= row['Latitud'] <= 20.826500) and (-101.877600 <= row['Longitud'] <= -98.948600):
        row['Tramo'] = 'Foraneo'
    else:
        row['Tramo'] = 'Otro'
```

Debe haber una mejor manera de hacerlo, pues si esta usando pandas la idea no es iterar es super ineficiente con grandes volúmenes de datos.

Véase: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/13692418

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona perfectamente.